# How to use a String as a resource ID

Tags: android, resources, drawable

*Update - solved**
What I was looking for was how to get the Resource ID.  It's difficult to formulate a question when you don't know what you don't know, but the two guys that answered it within a matter of minutes seemed to understand.  Thanks, guys.

Here is the code I was finally able to use without having to load all 32 bitmaps while using a String to identify which specific one I was after.

```
StartCalc session = new StartCalc(context);
    int findDate = session.findDate(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < daysTil.length; i++) {
        String numbers = "numbers" + i;
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(numbers, "drawable", getPackageName());

        if (i == findDate) {
            ivNumbers.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId));
        }
    }
```

*Original question**
I'm trying to use a for loop to fill an array of Bitmaps, from 0 to 32, but I can't figure out how to use the String "numbers" (identified on line 3) to populate the address required by the BitmapFactory (referenced on line 5).  Here's the code of me filling the array **two** ways. The long way has issues taking up too much memory, and since I only need one of these images based on the date, I'm hoping there's a way to do this.

```
private void setNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        String numbers = "R.drawable.numbers" + i;
        Log.e(TAG, numbers);
        daysTil[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), numbers);
    }

    daysTil[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers0);
    daysTil[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers1);
    daysTil[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers2);
    daysTil[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers3);
    daysTil[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers4);
    daysTil[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers5);
    daysTil[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers6);
    daysTil[7] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers7);
    daysTil[8] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers8);
    daysTil[9] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers9);
    daysTil[10] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers10);
    daysTil[11] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers11);
    daysTil[12] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers12);
    daysTil[13] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers13);
    daysTil[14] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers14);
    daysTil[15] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers15);
    daysTil[16] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers16);
    daysTil[17] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers17);
    daysTil[18] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers18);
    daysTil[19] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers19);
    daysTil[20] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers20);
    daysTil[21] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers21);
    daysTil[22] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers22);
    daysTil[23] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers23);
    daysTil[24] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers24);
    daysTil[25] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers25);
    daysTil[26] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers26);
    daysTil[27] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers27);
    daysTil[28] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers28);
    daysTil[29] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers29);
    daysTil[30] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers30);
    daysTil[31] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers31);
    daysTil[32] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.numbers32);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this method to find the resource id of the drawable:

```
String numbers = "numbers" + i;

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(numbers, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Reference: [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

The Resources class has this method:

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

So the complete statement could look somewhat like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    String numbers = "R.drawable.numbers" + i;
    Log.e(TAG, numbers);
    Resources resources = <context>.getResources();
    daysTil[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                    resources.getIdentifier ("numbers" +i, "drawable",
                                                  <context>.getPackageName());
}
```

(note: this code is untested - it's just for demonstration)